# Website works remotely but not on the server itself when called by domain

Tags: windows, iis

I am using Windows Server 2019 and in IIS 10 I have created a website and I have bound it to both: "localhost" and "mydomain.com" on port 80.

mydomain.com works correctly from any client but on the server only when I call "localhost" it works otherwise I get the following error (when called by domain):

[image]

Comment: This is almost a certainty to be a hairpinning issue. And as such, isn't something I'd be particularly keen to worry about. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking there is a problem with my server configuration

Comment: Did you do `nslookup mydomain.com` on the server itself? Does the answer differ if you ask the same on the client where web site worked?